# How do I change Fork file location on my PC

Tags: git, fork, git-fork

For our Assignment, we are using GIT and FORK for file sharing. Recently got a new SSD so now my IDE can't override onto my old file location how do I change the fork repository location?

Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about the git-fork client https://git-fork.com/, if it's anything like any other git client - it doesn't really care where you repository is - simply copy the repository to the new location, and open the new copied repository using Fork

Comment: I can do this but if I change the new copy, I am unable to commit the changes. Thas is why I would like to change the location in Fork. I am not even sure if it is possible. Thank you anyway for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only option is to commit your changes then re- clone the project through bash into the new directory